# How to get the type of a variable using reflection c#

Tags: c#, reflection

I have been looking for a while - and I cant find an answer that works....

I am just trying to to find out the type of a variable or property in a class using reflection...

```
   foreach (XElement items in nodes)
                {
                    Game newGame = new Game();
                    FieldInfo[] fields = newGame.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance |
                       BindingFlags.Static |
                       BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                       BindingFlags.Public);

                    foreach(XAttribute item in items.Attributes())
                    {
                        foreach (FieldInfo f in fields)
                        {

                            if (f.Name.Remove(0,1) == item.Name.LocalName)
                            {

                                if (GetTypeOrUnderlyingType(f) == typeof(Int32))
                                {
                                    Type type = typeof(Int32).DeclaringType;
                                    f.SetValue(newGame, Convert.ChangeType(item.Value, type));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

 public Type GetTypeOrUnderlyingType(object o)
        {
            Type type = o.GetType();
            if (!type.IsGenericType) { return type; }
            return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        }
```

And Game is a generated class via linq...
I just want to get the type of the field so I know whether i need to cast my xml item.value....

Comment: Any reason you're using reflection for this instead of `typeof`  or `a.var1.GetType()`

Comment: well im using reflection to get and set the fields...as I am reading in an xml file and then trying to set fields based on xml using reflection...I tried doing f.GetDeclaringType i.e. (foreach field f in fields) but it returns A instead of int... and f.gettype() returns null

Comment: i will update question...

Comment: Side note: it looks like you are using "variable" as synonym of "field" (based on "variable or property in a class"). It is very unusual to call "field" this way - you may want to update title/question if indeed you talk about fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the property value of the field use the FieldInfo classes [FieldType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.fieldtype.aspx) property

```
foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in typeof(A).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance |
                               BindingFlags.Static |
                               BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                               BindingFlags.Public))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(fieldInfo.FieldType.Name);
                }
```

Comment: That returns back Nullable - assumming that instead of actually being int its int? but it doesnt tell me its an int though...

Comment: +1 as it answers the question as asked. @user2238556, please update your question with what your problem actually is. You may need to add handling for some structural types (like `Nullable`, `Array`, `List<T>` if you want to write more generic serialization).